# Obtener a través de una consulta Select MySQL año/semana/año/dia con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito una consulta mysql para sacar año/semana del año/día de semana.

También si se puede hacer a través de php.

**ejemplo 1:**

tengo esta fecha:

01/10/2020.

este seria el resultado esperado: 204004

año:20
semana año:40
día de semana:04

**ejemplo2:**

02/10/2020.

año:20
semana año:40
día semana:05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo en PHP, de ese modo simplificarías los datos que se transportan desde la base de datos (haciendo simplemente un `SELECT columnaDeLaFecha FROM` y luego usando el dato en `columnaDeLaFecha` para crear un objeto `DateTime` de PHP y sacarle la información que necesites mediante el método `format`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
# Creamos el objeto según el formato en que viene d/m/Y
$mDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','01/10/2020'); 
# Sacamos la información que necesitamos
# NÓTESE que REUTILIZAMOS el mismo objeto ($mDate), aplicando format->
echo "Año: ".$mDate->format('y').PHP_EOL; 

/*
    'N' fue añadido en PHP 5.1.0
    Se computa el día partiendo desde 1=Lunes
    Si se quiere que 1=domingo, habría que restar 1
    En versiones anteriores a PHP 5.1.0 hay que usar 'w'
    y el conteo es partiendo de 0=domingo ...
    y habría que operar según se requiera domingo o lunes como 1er día
*/
echo "Día de la semana: 0".$mDate->format('N').PHP_EOL; 
echo "Día del año: ".$mDate->format('W');
```

**Salida:**

```
Año: 20
Día de la semana: 04
Día del año: 40
```

### Observaciones

1. Al usar `format` con el objeto `DateTime` hemos pasado valores como `y`, `N`, `W`, etc. Son valores predefinidos que nos permiten obtener información por separado del objeto. Todos los valores posibles [están explicados aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).
2. La hora se creará con la zona horaria que tenga el servidor por defecto. Si quieres otra zona horaria la puedes pasar como tercer parámetro en la llamada a `createFromFormat()`, por ejemplo:

   ```
   $mDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','01/10/2020', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Darwin'));
   ```

   PERO, para el tipo de dato que requieres aquí, no creo que la zona horaria afecte en nada.
3. `createFromFormat()` no es la única forma de crear objetos `DateTime`, aquí usamos ese método estático porque nos interesa crear un objeto partiendo de un dato con un determinado formato. [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) es una clase más amplia que sirve para operar con todo lo que sea fecha y hora en PHP. Del mismo modo, `format()` es sólo un método, entre muchos, que posee dicha clase.

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad es que utilices date (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y le añadas el formato que quieres. En tu caso, lo mas parecido es:

```
echo date('yWn');
```

esto te devuelve algo como:

```
204110
```

Pero date cuenta que el formato debe ser segun tu conveniencia; en este caso `y` representa el año en 2 digitos, `W` el numero de la semana del año, y `n` el numero del dia.
En el caso del dia, se numera de 1 a 7 (pero hay otros calendarios que numeran desde 0-6).

Te recomiendo que revises la doc y juegues con el formato que te interese.

En caso que necesites indicar la fecha (no sea la actual) tambien puedes hacer:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); // aqui indicas tu la fecha
echo $date->format('yWn');          // tu formato de salida
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes obtener con la función semana de *MySQL*:

**MySQL WEEK() Function:**

```
SELECT WEEK("2020-10-01");
```

Resultado: 39

Y de ahí jugar con las salidas que quieras concatenando el año, también con la semana del año:

---

**MySQL WEEKOFYEAR() Function:**

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2020-10-01");
```

Resultado: 40

---

O con:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY("2020-10-01");
```

Resultado:  3

Comment: en dia de la semana debe dar 4, tiene algo qu ver con la sona horia? veo que en tu respuesta dio 3 igualmente que semana que te dio 39, y debe dar 40, tiene que ver con la zona horaria?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función WEEK().

**MySQL WEEK (date, [mode])**

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20');
        -> 7
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20',0);
        -> 7
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20',1);
        -> 8
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-12-31',1);
        -> 53
```

El valor para el parámetro mode lo puedes ver en esta tabla:

```
+------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| Mode | First day of week | Range |  Week 1 is the first week …   |
+------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
|    0 | Sunday            | 0-53  | with a Sunday in this year    |
|    1 | Monday            | 0-53  | with 4 or more days this year |
|    2 | Sunday            | 1-53  | with a Sunday in this year    |
|    3 | Monday            | 1-53  | with 4 or more days this year |
|    4 | Sunday            | 0-53  | with 4 or more days this year |
|    5 | Monday            | 0-53  | with a Monday in this year    |
|    6 | Sunday            | 1-53  | with 4 or more days this year |
|    7 | Monday            | 1-53  | with a Monday in this year    |
+------+-------------------+-------+-------------------------------+
```